# Spring Boot Security - how to put all endpoint under the role of User and admin?

Tags: spring, spring-security

I'm using Spring Boot 2.7.1 and Spring Security, somehow all my endpoints are giving me There was an unexpected error (type=Forbidden, status=403). How can I put all these endpoints under the ADMIN and USER?

[image]

Code

```
package com.example.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;

@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig {
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests()
                //.requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/couponapi/coupons/**", HttpMethod.GET.name()))
                .requestMatchers(
                        new AntPathRequestMatcher("/couponapi/coupons/{code:^[A-Z]*$}", HttpMethod.GET.name()),
                        new AntPathRequestMatcher("/showReg", HttpMethod.GET.name()),
                        new AntPathRequestMatcher("/showCreateCoupon", HttpMethod.GET.name()),
                        new AntPathRequestMatcher("/showGetCoupon", HttpMethod.GET.name())
                )

                .hasAnyRole("USER", "ADMIN")
                .requestMatchers(
                        new AntPathRequestMatcher("/couponapi/coupons/", HttpMethod.POST.name())
                )
                .hasRole("ADMIN")
                .mvcMatchers("/", "/login", "/logout", "/showReg", "/registerUser").permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .disable();

        http.securityContext(securityContext -> securityContext.requireExplicitSave(true));
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class)
                .build();
    }
}
```

Controller

```
@Controller
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private SecurityService securityService;

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepo;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder encoder;

    @GetMapping("/showReg")
    public String showRegistrationPage() {
        return "registerUser";
    }

    @PostMapping("/registerUser")
    public String register(User user) {
        user.setPassword(encoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        userRepo.save(user);
        return "login";
    }

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String showLoginPage() {
        return "login";
    }

    @PostMapping("/login")
    public String login(String email, String password) {
        boolean loginResponse = securityService.login(email, password);
        if (loginResponse) {
            return "index";
        }
        return "login";
    }
}
```

RestController.java

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/couponapi")
@CrossOrigin
public class CouponRestController {

    @Autowired
    CouponRepository repo;

    @PostMapping("/coupons")
    public Coupon create(@RequestBody Coupon coupon) {
        return repo.save(coupon);
    }

    @GetMapping("/coupons/{code}")
    public Coupon getCoupon(@PathVariable("code") String code) {
        return repo.findByCode(code);
    }
}
```

UserDetailsService.java

```
@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findByEmail(username);
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found for email" + username);
        }
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getEmail(), user.getPassword(),
                user.getRoles());
    }
}
```

SecurityServiceImpl.java

```
@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findByEmail(username);
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found for email" + username);
        }
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getEmail(), user.getPassword(),
                user.getRoles());
    }
}
```

Comment: you are doing request to `/showCreateCoupon` but in your controller layer i don`t see this endpoint. It is a normal behavior.